# JavaScript code doesn't run inside PHP in WP plugin

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress

I read a few topics like "Javascript inside PHP doesn't work" but I couldn't find a solution. I have a WP plugin that sends emails when someone clicks on a button. Also when an email has been sent a PHP pop-up with confirmation appears. I think it's in the part where "wp_mail()" is. When an email was sent properly, I want to run some JS, right before PHP message. So I tried to do this outside PHP (first attempt) and through echo (second attempt below). I don't see these console logs. Also when I have this JS there, then this PHP alert doesn't show. When I remove it, it works. This code is run for sure because when I change the text in PHP alert message I see it. Also above this function is another function "add_action('wp_footer'..) and there is only JS, and this JS works, when I change something. I can't understand why it doesn't work there.

Function where I have problem:

```
function updateRequest()
{
    $admin_email = get_option('admin_email');
    $senderEmail = empty(trim(get_option('settings_page_sender_email'))) ? "no-reply@".$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] : get_option('settings_page_sender_email');
    $order = wc_get_order($_POST['orderID']);
    $title = empty(trim(get_option('settings_page_email_title')))?"“[UPDATE REQUEST]”":get_option('settings_page_email_title');
    $recipient = $admin_email;

    $subject = str_replace('[PRODUCTTITLE]', $_POST['productTitle'], $title);
    $message = " &nbsp;";
    $headers = array(
        'Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8',
        'From: '.$_POST['name'].' <'.$senderEmail.'>',
        'Reply-To: '.$_POST['name'].' <'.$_POST['email'].'>'
    );

    if(wp_mail( $recipient, $subject, $message, $headers )){
        
        ?>
        <script type="text/javascript">console.log("Data alert");</script>
        <?php
        
        echo'<script type="text/javascript">console.log("Data alert");</script>';
    
        $confirmationTxt = empty(trim(get_option('settings_page_confirmation_text'))) ? "Request has been sent" : get_option('settings_page_confirmation_text');
        wp_send_json_success($confirmationTxt , $status_code = null );  

    }else{
        wp_send_json_error( "Something Went Wrong ...!", $status_code );
    }
}
```

And this is the whole file

```
<?php

// If this file is called directly, abort.
if ( ! defined( 'WPINC' ) ) {
    die;
}

function console_log($output, $with_script_tags = true) {
    $js_code = 'console.log(' . json_encode($output, JSON_HEX_TAG) . 
');';
    if ($with_script_tags) {
        $js_code = '<script>' . $js_code . '</script>';
    }
    echo $js_code;
}

/**
 * Currently plugin version.
 * Start at version 1.0.0 and use SemVer - https://semver.org
 * Rename this for your plugin and update it as you release new versions.
 */
define( 'VIRTUAL_PRODUCT_WOOCOMMERCE_UPDATE_REQUEST_VERSION', '1.0.0' );

// Define global constants
$plugin_data = get_file_data( __FILE__, array( 'name'=>'Plugin Name', 'version'=>'Version', 'text'=>'Text Domain' ) );
function VPWUR_constants( $constant_name, $value ) {
    $constant_name_prefix = 'VPWUR_VERSION';
    $constant_name = $constant_name_prefix . $constant_name;
    if ( !defined( $constant_name ) )
        define( $constant_name, $value );
}
VPWUR_constants( 'DIR', dirname( plugin_basename( __FILE__ ) ) );
VPWUR_constants( 'BASE', plugin_basename( __FILE__ ) );
VPWUR_constants( 'URL', plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ ) );
VPWUR_constants( 'PATH', plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ ) );
VPWUR_constants( 'SLUG', dirname( plugin_basename( __FILE__ ) ) );
VPWUR_constants( 'NAME', $plugin_data['name'] );
VPWUR_constants( 'VERSION', $plugin_data['version'] );
VPWUR_constants( 'TEXT', $plugin_data['text'] );
VPWUR_constants( 'PREFIX', '' );
VPWUR_constants( 'SETTINGS', '' );

/**
 * The code that runs during plugin activation.
 * This action is documented in includes/class-virtual-product-woocommerce-update-request-activator.php
 */
function activate_virtual_product_woocommerce_update_request() {
    require_once plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ ) . 'includes/class-virtual-product-woocommerce-update-request-activator.php';
    Virtual_Product_Woocommerce_Update_Request_Activator::activate();
}

/**
 * The code that runs during plugin deactivation.
 * This action is documented in includes/class-virtual-product-woocommerce-update-request-deactivator.php
 */
function deactivate_virtual_product_woocommerce_update_request() {
    require_once plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ ) . 'includes/class-virtual-product-woocommerce-update-request-deactivator.php';
    Virtual_Product_Woocommerce_Update_Request_Deactivator::deactivate();
}

register_activation_hook( __FILE__, 'activate_virtual_product_woocommerce_update_request' );
register_deactivation_hook( __FILE__, 'deactivate_virtual_product_woocommerce_update_request' );

/**
 * The core plugin class that is used to define internationalization,
 * admin-specific hooks, and public-facing site hooks.
 */
require plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ ) . 'includes/class-virtual-product-woocommerce-update-request.php';

/**
 * Begins execution of the plugin.
 *
 * Since everything within the plugin is registered via hooks,
 * then kicking off the plugin from this point in the file does
 * not affect the page life cycle.
 *
 * @since    1.0.0
 */
function run_virtual_product_woocommerce_update_request() {
    $plugin = new Virtual_Product_Woocommerce_Update_Request();
    $plugin->run();
}
run_virtual_product_woocommerce_update_request();

add_action('wp_footer', function ()
{
    echo "<br><br><br><br><br>";
    echo 'Hamza';
   if (shortcode_exists( 'UpdateRequstBtn' )) {
        echo "<pre>Shortcode Registered</pre>";
    } 
});
/* Adding CSS style for public */
function my_enqueued_assets() {
    wp_enqueue_style('virtual-product-woocommerce-update-request-public', plugin_dir_url(__FILE__) . '/public/css/virtual-product-woocommerce-update-request-public.css', '', time());
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_enqueued_assets');


function updateRequstBtn($atts) {
  global $product, $woocommerce;
  $html = "";
  if (method_exists($product, 'get_id')) {
    $id = $product->get_id();
  }
  $atts = shortcode_atts( array(
        'id' => @$id,
    ), $atts, 'UpdateRequstBtn' );
  // echo $atts['id'];
  $product = new WC_Product($atts['id']);
  if (empty($atts['id']) || $atts['id'] == 0 || !get_current_user_id()) {
      return;
  }
  $order = has_bought_items([$atts['id']]);
  if (!$order) {
      // you can remove this no orders from here ... just remove the text "No Orders"
    return "";
  }
  // // print_r($order->get_billing_email());
  $btnText = empty(trim(get_option( 'settings_page_btn_txt' ))) ? "Update Request": get_option( 'settings_page_btn_txt' );
  $html .= '<div class="woocommerce-product-gallery vpwur-button-div">';
  $html .= '<a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="updateRequest(this);" class="button vpwur-button-a" 
   data-email="'.$order->get_billing_email().'"
   data-orderID="'.$order->get_id().'"
   data-productTitle="'.get_the_title($atts['id']).'"
   data-name="'.$order->get_billing_first_name()." ".$order->get_billing_last_name().'"
   >'. $btnText .'</a>';
  $html .= '<p class="vpwur-sending-txt-pre">Trwa wysylanie zadania...</div>';
  return $html;
}

add_shortcode( 'UpdateRequstBtn', 'UpdateRequstBtn' );

/**
 * Show number list of downloadable files for group product
 *
 * @param array $download
 * @return void
 */
/*function prefix_downloads_column_download_file( array $download ) {
    // print_r($download);
    echo '<a href="', $download['download_url'], '" download>', $download['download_name'], '</a>';
    // do_shortcode( '[UpdateRequstBtn id="'.$download['product_id'].'"]' );
    // echo shortcode_exists( 'UpdateRequstBtn' );
}

add_action( 'woocommerce_account_downloads_column_download-file', 'prefix_downloads_column_download_file' );*/
add_action( 'woocommerce_account_downloads_column_update-request', function( $download ) {
    if (get_option( 'enable_download_page_btn' )) {
        echo do_shortcode( '[UpdateRequstBtn id="'.$download['product_id'].'"]' );
    }
} );

add_filter( 'woocommerce_account_downloads_columns', function( $columns ) {
 
    if (get_option( 'enable_download_page_btn' )) {
        // Add Column
        $columnName = empty(trim(get_option( 'download_page_column_name' ))) ? "Update Request": get_option( 'download_page_column_name' );
        $columns['update-request'] = $columnName;
    }
    // Return
    return $columns; 
} );


add_action('wp_footer', function ()
{
    ?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function updateRequest(e) {
            var data = {
                'action': 'updateRequest',
                'name': e.dataset.name,      // We pass php values differently!
                'email': e.dataset.email,      // We pass php values differently!
                'orderID': e.dataset.orderid,      // We pass php values differently!
                'productTitle': e.dataset.producttitle,      // We pass php values differently!
            };
            // console.log(data);
            jQuery.post('<?php echo admin_url('admin-ajax.php') ?>', data, function(response) {
                alert(response.data);
                // alert('Got this from the server: ' + response);
            });
            
            /* Changing CSS for sending email message under button */

            const confirmTxtsList = Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName('vpwur-sending-txt-pre'));
            confirmTxtsList.forEach(p => {
            
               p.classList.remove('vpwur-sending-txt-pre');
               p.classList.add('vpwur-sending-txt-on');
            });
        }
    </script>
    <?php
});
add_action('wp_ajax_updateRequest','updateRequest');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_updateRequest','updateRequest');
function updateRequest()
{
    $admin_email = get_option('admin_email');
    $senderEmail = empty(trim(get_option('settings_page_sender_email'))) ? "no-reply@".$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] : get_option('settings_page_sender_email');
    $order = wc_get_order($_POST['orderID']);
    $title = empty(trim(get_option('settings_page_email_title')))?"“[UPDATE REQUEST]”":get_option('settings_page_email_title');
    $recipient = $admin_email;

    $subject = str_replace('[PRODUCTTITLE]', $_POST['productTitle'], $title);
    $message = " &nbsp;";
    $headers = array(
        'Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8',
        'From: '.$_POST['name'].' <'.$senderEmail.'>',
        'Reply-To: '.$_POST['name'].' <'.$_POST['email'].'>'
    );

    if(wp_mail( $recipient, $subject, $message, $headers )){
        
        ?>
        <script type="text/javascript">console.log("Data alert");</script>
        <?php
        
        echo'<script type="text/javascript">console.log("Data alert");</script>';
    
        $confirmationTxt = empty(trim(get_option('settings_page_confirmation_text'))) ? "Request has been sent" : get_option('settings_page_confirmation_text');
        wp_send_json_success($confirmationTxt , $status_code = null );  

    }else{
        wp_send_json_error( "Something Went Wrong ...!", $status_code );
    }
}
function has_bought_items($prod_arr=[]) {
    $bought = false;

    // Set HERE ine the array your specific target product IDs
    // $prod_arr = array( '21', '67' );

    // Get all customer orders
    $customer_orders = get_posts( array(
        'numberposts' => -1,
        'meta_key'    => '_customer_user',
        'meta_value'  => get_current_user_id(),
        'post_type'   => 'shop_order', // WC orders post type
        'post_status' => 'wc-completed' // Only orders with status "completed"
    ) );
    foreach ( $customer_orders as $customer_order ) {
        // Updated compatibility with WooCommerce 3+
        $order_id = method_exists( $customer_order, 'get_id' ) ? $customer_order->get_id() : $customer_order->id;
        $order = wc_get_order( $customer_order );

        // Iterating through each current customer products bought in the order
        foreach ($order->get_items() as $item) {
            // WC 3+ compatibility
            if ( version_compare( WC_VERSION, '3.0', '<' ) ) 
                $product_id = $item['product_id'];
            else
                $product_id = $item->get_product_id();

            // Your condition related to your 2 specific products Ids
            if ( in_array( $product_id, $prod_arr ) ) 
                $bought = $order;
        }
    }
    // return "true" if one the specifics products have been bought before by customer
    return $bought;
}
```

PS there is no "?>" at the end, as this is main plugin file and must be part of some other file probably.

Comment: Javascript is client side, and PHP is server side. You cannot run Javascript inside PHP.

Comment: Also printing out some script tags, doesn't mean running JS inside PHP. If you were to run this inside a PHP CLI, you would see that it only prints a text, and doesn't run any JS code.

Comment: `wp_send_json_success` sounds like it's sending a Json result, which probably means that this is some AJAX request, of which the response is parsed by a client side script. By adding these script tags, you will have made the Json response invalid. You won't get your message (since it was never processed as HTML with a script in it anyway), and also will have impeded the normal flow of this response. 
If anything, you can try to figure out which script processes this response, add your logic in there, and if needed, add in some extra information in the Json response to support that logic.

Comment: For the PS, the closing `?>` is optional in PHP, to make sure you don't accidentally render some unwanted whitespace at the end of the file. The script may be part of a bigger script, but `?>` has nothing to do with that.